# Sequelize between two dates

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am making a booking application, here when I want to create the booking, I must put a condition that the user cannot make a reservation of the room if it is already reserved for another one
So here is my code, it does not work it gives me this error:
throw new Error(`Invalid value ${logger.inspect(val)}`);
^
Error: Invalid value { from: { '$between': [Array] } }
I think the error is in the format but I don't know how to write it correctly
this is booking code :

```
router.route('/BookingRoom').post(async(req, res) => {
    const BookingRoom = new Booking({
      room_id : req.body.room_id,
      user_id : req.body.user_id,
      endTime : req.body.endTime,
      startTime : req.body.startTime,
    });
     const start = await Booking.findOne({where:{startTime :new Date(req.body.startTime)}})
     const end = await Booking.findOne({where:{endTime :new Date(req.body.endTime)}})
    const book = await Booking.findAll({where: {
      $or: [{
        from: {
            $between: [ start, end]
        }
    }, {
        to: {
            $between: [start, end]
        }
    }] ,room_id :req.body.room_id }});
    if(!book){
      BookingRoom.save()
    .then(Booking => {
        res.json(Booking);
        console.log('the room '+req.body.room_id +' has been successfully reserved for you')
        }
    )
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send((err).toString()));
    }
    else{
      console.log("err");
    return res.send(500, 'Booking exist already at this time');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query should be like this.

```
const book = await Booking.findAll({
  where: {
    startTime: {
      [Op.between]: [new Date(start.startTime), new Date(end.endTime)],
    },
    room_id: req.body.room_id,
  },
})
```

because `start` and `end` variables are instances of `Booking`.

Comment: I try it but also there is a problem , this the new error :  [Op.between]: [new Date(start.startTime), new Date(end.endTime)],
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'startTime')

Comment: It means either the `startTime` value is missing or there is no booking with that `startTime`, and `start` variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your variables.
Accordingly to

> const start = await Booking.findOne({where:{startTime :new Date(req.body.startTime)}})
> const end = await Booking.findOne({where:{endTime :new Date(req.body.endTime)}})

Your variables are instances of `Booking` model not `Date`.
Firstly you have to retrieve dates from `start` and `end` variables.

```js
const { startTime } = start;
const { endTime } = end;
```

Then use it inside `between`

```js
...
$between: [startTime, endTime]
...
```

Comment: He didn't accept the { < and >} how can i use these operators?

Comment: @hidy what do you mean?